# Increase/Decrease Play Speed of a WAV file Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, wav

I want to change play speed (increase or decrease) of a certain WAV audio file using python wave module.

I tried below thing :

1. Read frame rate of input file.
2. Double the frame rate.
3. Write a new wave file with increased frame rate using output_wave.setparams() function.

But its not working out.

Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: It would help if you could post a) the code you're using, and b) a more detailed description of the problem - ie, *how* is it 'not working out'?

Comment: I know It's late please see my answer.
[I wrote the whole program for different playback speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62715422/2866150)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

WOW!

if you no matter to change the pitch when you increase or decrease the speed, you can just change the sample rate !

Can be very simple using python:

```
import wave

CHANNELS = 1
swidth = 2
Change_RATE = 2

spf = wave.open('VOZ.wav', 'rb')
RATE=spf.getframerate()
signal = spf.readframes(-1)

wf = wave.open('changed.wav', 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(swidth)
wf.setframerate(RATE*Change_RATE)
wf.writeframes(signal)
wf.close()
```

increase or decrease the variable `Change_RATE` !

Now if you need keep the pitch untouched, you need do same type of overlap-add method !

Comment: Another question, if I craft a wave file which has total 20000 frames and the frame rate is 500, then the period of the wav sound should be 40 seconds, But actually its becoming 1 min 19 seconds..

NUMBER_OF_FRAME = 20000
FRAME_RATE = 500
op = wave.open('random.wav', 'w')
op.setparams((1, 2, FRAME_RATE, NUMBER_OF_FRAME, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_FRAME):
 byte1 = struct.pack('h',randint(0,255))
 byte2 = struct.pack('h',randint(0,255))
 op.writeframes(byte1+byte2)
op.close()

Why its happening ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the sampling frequency it has no influence on audiable playback speed. 
You can play around with this using SoX [Sound eXchange, the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

There is pySonic library for python look at UserSpeed method of the Song object.
[pySonic Python wrapper of FMOD Sound library](http://pysonic.sourceforge.net/doc/song.html)